# json_encode not encoding long string

Tags: php, mysql, json, pdo

in my script json_enocode is encoding string or there may be some other problem ?

first Let me show all things that i have in my configuration and codes

table structure

```
CREATE TABLE `dc_songs` (
 `songs_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `song_name` varchar(2000) NOT NULL,
 `lyrics` text NOT NULL,
 `created_time` datetime NOT NULL,
 `is_deleted` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
 `delete_reason` text NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`songs_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Here is string that i have updated in one row of given table

```
UPDATE `dc_songs` SET `lyrics` = 'Your account privacy is very important to us. You are like our family member. You can manage all your content via privacy settings. Content with privacy settings public visible to every user of this web site. You must read how content will be displayed according to your privacy in Help Section. 2.Safety

We do our best keep this web site safe but this not always depend on us, for that you will need to follow this safety Rules.

    You will not post content that is copyrighted or Unauthorized
    You will not use someone’s account
    You will not irritate users in anyways.
    You will not upload content like virus or spam.
    You will not share content that can hate someone, threatening, or pornographic.
    You will not do act that can affect this web site.
    You must provide all your original details.
    You will not use, download or share someone’s content like personal information, photographs, videos or any other that is not yours.
    You will not force user to do act that make our samaj down.
    You will not force user to fight against your enemy.
    You will not encourage people to do violence.
    You will not use this web site to do anything unlawful, misleading, malicious, or discriminatory. ' WHERE `dc_songs`.`songs_id` = 2;
```

query i am using

```
$query = "SELECT songs_id,lyrics,s.username,song_name,p.fullname
            FROM dc_songs s
            LEFT JOIN profile p ON p.username=s.username
            ORDER by songs_id DESC";
        $r=$db->run($query);
```

after encoding $r i am getting this output

**[{"songs_id":"2","lyrics":null,"username":"bhavik","song_name":"some name 1","fullname":"Bhavik  Thakor Garasiya"}]**

**UPDATE :**

output of print_r($r);

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [songs_id] => 2 [lyrics] => Your account privacy is very important to us. You are like our family member. You can manage all your content via privacy settings. Content with privacy settings public visible to every user of this web site. You must read how content will be displayed according to your privacy in Help Section. 2.Safety We do our best keep this web site safe but this not always depend on us, for that you will need to follow this safety Rules. You will not post content that is copyrighted or Unauthorized You will not use someone’s account You will not irritate users in anyways. You will not upload content like virus or spam. You will not share content that can hate someone, threatening, or pornographic. You will not do act that can affect this web site. You must provide all your original details. You will not use, download or share someone’s content like personal information, photographs, videos or any other that is not yours. You will not force user to do act that make our samaj down. You will not force user to fight against your enemy. You will not encourage people to do violence. You will not use this web site to do anything unlawful, misleading, malicious, or discriminatory. [username] => bhavik [song_name] => some name 1 [fullname] => Bhavik Thakor Garasiya ) )
```

Comment: And I assume you have checked that the lyrics really gets retrieved when you run your query? That is that the lyrics are there before you try to encode it to JSON?

Comment: yes it is there i did var_dump and print_r also

Comment: Hmmm this is a longshot so I won't put it as a suggested answer but when you have a newline instead of inserting it like you have done (pressing enter), try using \n instead and see if that helps. I don't think json handles newlines very well.

Comment: @user1511547, Let's see that debugging output.

Comment: i also replaced \n but still it is not encoding ....

Comment: @Brad i don't know how to debug

Comment: @user1511547, "yes it is there i did var_dump and print_r also", That's the output we need to see.

Answer (score 1):

I've run some tests and this character `’` seems to be breaking the json enconding for the text.

Here's the script I used to test the data. The first part tries to encode the text as provided, then the `’` character is replaced by `'` and the encoding works.

```
<?php
$json = array('data' => htmlentities('Your account privacy is very important to us. You are like our family member. You can manage all your content via privacy settings. Content with privacy settings public visible to every user of this web site. You must read how content will be displayed according to your privacy in Help Section. 2.Safety

We do our best keep this web site safe but this not always depend on us, for that you will need to follow this safety Rules.

    You will not post content that is copyrighted or Unauthorized
    You will not use someone’s account
    You will not irritate users in anyways.
    You will not upload content like virus or spam.
    You will not share content that can hate someone, threatening, or pornographic.
    You will not do act that can affect this web site.
    You must provide all your original details.
    You will not use, download or share someone’s content like personal information, photographs, videos or any other that is not yours.
    You will not force user to do act that make our samaj down.
    You will not force user to fight against your enemy.
    You will not encourage people to do violence.
    You will not use this web site to do anything unlawful, misleading, malicious, or discriminatory. '));

echo '<pre>';
echo json_encode($json);
echo "\n";

$json['data'] = str_replace('’', "'", $json['data']);

echo json_encode($json);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Here's the output:

```
{"data":null}
{"data":"Your account privacy is very important to us. You are like our family member. You can manage all your content via privacy settings. Content with privacy settings public visible to every user of this web site. You must read how content will be displayed according to your privacy in Help Section. 2.Safety\r\n\r\nWe do our best keep this web site safe but this not always depend on us, for that you will need to follow this safety Rules.\r\n\r\n    You will not post content that is copyrighted or Unauthorized\r\n    You will not use someone's account\r\n    You will not irritate users in anyways.\r\n    You will not upload content like virus or spam.\r\n    You will not share content that can hate someone, threatening, or pornographic.\r\n    You will not do act that can affect this web site.\r\n    You must provide all your original details.\r\n    You will not use, download or share someone's content like personal information, photographs, videos or any other that is not yours.\r\n    You will not force user to do act that make our samaj down.\r\n    You will not force user to fight against your enemy.\r\n    You will not encourage people to do violence.\r\n    You will not use this web site to do anything unlawful, misleading, malicious, or discriminatory. "}
```

Comment: I just edited the code so that it uses the `str_replace` function. Try replacing the `’` for `'` in the lyrics and see if it works.